# MySQL trigger on INSERT not working properly

Tags: mysql

I have a simple MySQL Trigger on INSERT. I've tested it in MySQL Workbench and it works.

```
use `my database`;
DROP TRIGGER if exists after_tablea_insert;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_tablea_insert
AFTER INSERT
ON `my_table` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    insert into my_new_table (columnA,columnB,columnC,columnD) values(new.columnA,
       new.columnB,
       new.columnC,
       new.columnD);
END$$
```

However, when new data is inserted into my_table by an external data feed, the trigger only inserts the new data in my_table from columnA into my_new_table. ColumnB, columnC and columnD in my_new_table are given as null.

Any ideas why this might be the case?

The MySQL database is hosted on Google Cloud SQL. It's version 5.7 as per Google Cloud SQL requirements.

Data types:
my_table columnA = char(36) PK, columnB-D = text; my_new_table ColumnsA-D = text

Comment: Can you build a sqlfiddle to show your problem, because i can't replicate it

Comment: If it works in workbench then the problem is with your feed. What are {text} for??

Comment: @P.Salmon {text} it's to denote the data type for each column. Not sure it's correct practice to write as such tho

Comment: Looks like a typo in columns names. Show REAL structure for both tables and REAL trigger code.

Comment: 'Not sure it's correct practice to write as such tho ' - it's not and only serves to distract

Comment: @P.Salmon cool it's been corrected now.